# Button added to navigation Item always shows in blue colour

Tags: ios, xamarin, uibarbuttonitem, navigationbar, navigationitem

created `UIBarButtonItem` added Power Image to it.

```
barBtnPower =   new UIBarButtonItem (UIImage.FromBundle ("Images/Power@2x.png")
        , UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain
        , (sender, args) => {

           });
```

button added to navigation Item on right side.

```
this.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem (barBtn_Logout, true);
```

Issue is Power@2x.png is in green colour. but after run the application its shows in blue.

Can any one advice what i have done wrong here.

Comment: There is nothing wrong. Probably that navigationBar tintColor is blue. You can change that by using setTintColor: method of navigationBar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the always original rendering mode, if you don't want the navigation bar's tintColor property to effect your button's color.

```
barBtnPower =   new UIBarButtonItem (UIImage.FromBundle("Images/Power@2x.png").imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
        , UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain
        , (sender, args) => {});
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer with Swift 5

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "roulette")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(buttonRouletteClicked))
```